Ultimate cause of all evils
Whenever I see the news there is news of war, crimes, sufferings most of the time. What is the root cause of all the fights and the evil things that people do to other people ? And is there any way that evil can be eradicated ?

Human beings....

Why is this a philosophical question?

Why kill? Maybe educate them...

I actually meant to educate


Where there is duality, there is always fear of the other
Ramana Maharshi

Also

The root of all evil is the judgement This is evil!
ibid

which of course intensifies the well-known:

Judge not lest you be judged
Gospels

And the next generation of non-dual teacher after Ramana continued:

Where there is fear there will be anger
Nisargadatta Maharaj

More well known but equivalent is Bertrand Russell:

Fear is the main source of superstition, and one of the main sources of cruelty. To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom.
Neither a man nor a crowd nor a nation can be trusted to act humanely or to think sanely under the influence of a great fear

And where there is anger there will be violence
In the more usual dualistic format of the Bible

To me belongeth vengeance, and recompence; Their foot shall slide in due time: For the day of their calamity is at hand, And the things that shall come upon them make haste.
Deuteronomy

TO ME means to God/Lord/Yahweh...
That means not to us!!

In short we dont need more ferreting out of evil but instead Truth and Reconciliation with the main emphasis on the latter

"Where there is fear there will be anger" this is a complete non-sequitur as most of the quotes used. One can equally say "where there is bad sophistry, don't expect good solutions".

@NikosM. Interesting! Which other non sequiturs did Russell come up with?

Sigmund Freud wrote Civilization and Its Discontents. In this book he argues that love makes humans happy and cooperative work in society is necessary to prevent or delay human suffering. He concludes that a prudent ego, an ego that governs action by the use of reason, would value love and work in society. But in the English translation the translator does not use the word "prudence" or "prudent". It is implied in the context. Freud thinks reality compels the ego to strive to love and work in cooperation with others. This effort to love in personal life and work in cooperation with others is what I personally think we all inherently value in a prudent person.
But then Freud wonders why is it so hard for the human ego to become prudent, to experience the value of love and work, and to express those values in social harmony? His answers are all pessimistic. Natural and social forces are hostile to the ego. These forces make it difficult or impossible for the ego to experience and express happiness in the context of love and cooperative work. He concludes that the values of Communism; or of life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness; do not change aggressive human nature or overcome the limitations in the effort to love and work in harmony with each other!
